# Are Extron jacks standardized?

Tags: power-supply

A lot of Extron's devices ship with screw-down wirelock jacks. In this picture you can see both the screw down wire-lock and the jack. Is this a standard? Or, is it proprietary?

[image: Extron back of the device]

Answer (score 2):

That appears to be a fairly standard "Pluggable Terminal Block" type connector made by Phoenix Contact among others and available through any electronics distributor (Digikey, Mouser, etc.) Based on the style of the connector in the picture the pin pitch (distance between adjacent pins) is likely 3.81mm or so. (You would need to confirm.)

Here's an example of a part that might fit [MC 1,5/ 2-ST-3,81](https://www.phoenixcontact.com/en-pc/products/printed-circuit-board-connector-mc-15-2-st-381-1803578). There will be many different compatible variations listed by the manufacturer and distributors. e.g. like the one in the picture with the wire tie down part, ones with push in wire connections, etc.